# Symfony2 - A good way to manage users

Tags: authentication, symfony, bundle

I'm starting a new project with Symfony 2 and I have to create and manage some users with many personnal informations.
I must decide to chose a way to manage us and i wish receive some advice for chose Symfony 2 basic implementation or FOSUserBundle for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use FOSUserBundle. It's easy to install and configure.

At the most basic level, it lets you easily handle user storage and authentication through the database. It requires that your user entity conform to some of its 'standards', but after that you're free to write your user entity how you see fit.

AFAIK, it's also the most popular user management solution for Symfony2 right now, so you should be able to easily find resources/information for it online.

Comment: I couldn't make FOSUserBundle work. It took a lot of steps to install, and it ended in a non informative fatal error

Comment: @HappyDeveloper I'm not sure what to say. It takes 8 steps to install & configure FOSUserBundle. Surely the fatal error had some information you could use to pin point the problem?